# Should champion numbers per lane be matched?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are generally either 1 or 2 champions per team in each lane. Should you usually transfer champions between lanes, so that you don't have any players outnumbered in their lane?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please add more details or be more specific?

Comment: Since there are the same number of champions on each side, each 2v1 will be balanced by a 1v2 (simplifying assumption: same number of junglers on each side).  Thus, for every team that is disadvantaged by uneven matchups, there is a team (their opponent) that gains from it.  This makes it clear that it's situation-dependent and there can't be a single answer.

Comment: @Fabián: He's essentially asking 'If the opposing team laneswaps, should I laneswap as well to match?'

Comment: @Aaron - Good point. However, you do always have the option of laneswapping to rebalance the lanes. When should you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this is a really tough question to answer. The long and short of it is, there is no easy way to tell. Because LoL is so massive and there is an ever-changing meta, it's almost impoossible for me to tell you exactly when to do it and when not to.

But I'll try.

First, I'll start by giving some great articles. If you are really interested in becoming a better LoL player, I suggest you read these.

[Executing A Lane Swap](http://team-dignitas.net/articles/blogs/League-of-Legends/5365/Executing-a-Lane-Swap)

[Anatomy Of A 2v1 Swap](http://na.lolesports.com/articles/anatomy-2v1-lane-swap)

Now I'm going to assume you aren't on a pre-made team or go into a new game with an already-planned strategy.

The general tips are:

1. If you can sustain through a 2v1 lane, stay. Generally you will be okay and your 2v1 lane will come ahead just like theirs, so it's a wash. This is generally considered a good play, as you won't fall behind because it takes time swapping lanes.
2. If you are in the general area, like leeching a jungle camp or something, go ahead and swap. In normals, you want to try to keep everything as smooth as possible. If it won't take much time, go ahead and swap and carry on the game like you normally would.
3. Late/Early team comp: If you have an early game team composition, you might want to swap with them. Your team is going to be strong and you're going to have a better time in the early-mid game. Possibly look for an early gank from your jungler to help you out even more if things go a little crazy. If you have a late game team comp, just try to outlast their maneuvers. The basis for lane swaps is that a late-game team comp can get a little bit ahead early with a quick tower kill or map pressure.

If you have any other questions besides that, I'll be sure to update my answer.